# What is the meaning of "Additionally, and subject to our obligations hereunder and under X"?

Tags: terms-of-service, legal-terms

**Question:** What is the meaning of

> "Additionally, and subject to our obligations hereunder and under X"

?

**Background:**  The following section is part of a Terms of Use statement.
The rights that the user grants the company contradict the Data Sharing and Protection Policy:

> "Additionally, and subject to our obligations hereunder and under our
>   Data Sharing and Protection Policy with respect to any protected
>   health information (“PHI”), you grant [the company some rights that
>   contradicts the Data Sharing and Protection Policy.]”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of “Additionally, and subject to our obligations
>   hereunder and under X”?

In terms of the ToS you reproduced, it means that you grant only the rights that are **not** in conflict with the "PHI" portions of their Data Sharing and Protection Policy.

The clause "*subject to X*" means that *X* shall not be infringed. And the language "*subject to X with respect to Y*" is a *qualified* condition: *X* may be infringed except for *Y*.